# Conditional validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, conditional-statements

I have an ASP.NET web app (with C#). In it I have a form with several fields and validators. For one of the validators I only need to validate when:

- a certain textbox is empty
- and a certain record does not exist in the database (this is already handled).

I know I can't enable/disable the validator on page_load because something might be entered into that textbox. I also tried the following in the onclick event of the submit button but it didn't seem to work:

```
                    Validator1.Enabled = true;
                    Validator1.Validate();
```

I also tried `Page.Validate()` but that didn't work either...

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a customvalidator. Inside the Validation Event you have code like this pseudo code:

```
OnValidating(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
 if(CertainTextBox.Text.IsNullOrEmpty() && CertainRecordDoesNotExistInDB))
{
 // validate
// and set e.Valid to the desired validation output
}
else
{
 e.IsValid = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this things should be done by JavaScript on client. Then on submit you should validate at server side.